# After success message popup window and disable Submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have ajax function, which will get message from servlet. When message is success I want to show Success Message and Disable the submit button, how can I do it? Please help me, I really appreciate your support!

This is my code:

```
    <button id="send" onclick="ajaxSent()">SUBMIT</button>

function ajaxSent() { 
  $.ajax({
  url:'/ApiSend.cfm',
  data:{lname:l, pid:pid },
  type:'get',
  cache:false,
  success:function(data){

     if (data == null) {
      alert("Try Again!");
     }else if(data == 'success'){
      alert("Transaction Sent Successfully...");
     }
  },
 }
);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use disabled attribute.

```
success:function(data){
     if (data == null) {
      alert("Try Again!");
     }else if(data == 'success'){
      alert("Transaction Sent Successfully...");
     $("#send").prop("disabled", true);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

just do run this under success.

`$( "#send" ).remove();`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help!